# get mean of values that fit a specific criteria (pattern matching)

Tags: regex, r

I asked this question before and got a reply that solved it for me. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id                              weekdays              halflife
241732222300860000  Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 22    0.4166666667
241689170123309000  Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 19    0.3833333333
241686878137512000  Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 19    0.4
241651117396738000  Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 16    1.5666666667
241635163505820000  Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 15    0.95
241633401382265000  Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 15    2.3666666667
```

And I would like to get average half life of items that were created on Monday, then on Tuesday...etc. (My date range spans over 6 months).

To get the date values I used `strptime` and `difftime`. Also, I found the maximum halflife with `max(df$halflife)`, how can I find which id it corresponds to?

Reproducible code:

```
structure(list(id = c(241732222300860416, 241689170123309056, 
241686878137511936, 241651117396738048, 241635163505819648, 241633401382264832
), weekdays = c("Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 22", "Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 19", 
"Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 19", "Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 16", "Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 15", 
"Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 15"), halflife = structure(c(0.416666666666667, 
0.383333333333333, 0.4, 1.56666666666667, 0.95, 2.36666666666667
), class = "difftime", units = "mins")), .Names = c("id", 
"weekdays", "halflife"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

So now, I have an average half life value for all mondays, tuesdays...etc. How can I get the average value for all hours within those weekdays, i.e.: Average half life of all items that were created on all Mondays at 9am, then 10am, then 11am..etc. And then Tuesday at 9am, 10am, 11am..etc. The dates in the weekdays column is formatted so that the last number after the comma is the hour it was created at.  I am really bad with regular expressions and pattern matching, which is why I am asking this follow-up question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with base packages you can do following.

```
> mydf
            id                 weekdays       halflife
1 2.417322e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 22 0.4166667 mins
2 2.416892e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 19 0.3833333 mins
3 2.416869e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 19 0.4000000 mins
4 2.416511e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 16 1.5666667 mins
5 2.416352e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 15 0.9500000 mins
6 2.416334e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 15 2.3666667 mins
```

Instead of using regex, we can just use `strsplit` on each element of `weekdays`, `unlist` the result, and it back in 4 column format as `matrix` and `cbind` it back with `mydf`.

```
> mydf2 <- cbind(mydf, matrix(unlist(sapply(mydf$weekdays, strsplit, split=',')), byrow=TRUE, ncol=4, dimnames=list(1:nrow(mydf), c('Weekday', 'Day', 'Year', 'Hour'))))
> mydf2
            id                 weekdays       halflife Weekday     Day  Year Hour
1 2.417322e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 22 0.4166667 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   22
2 2.416892e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 19 0.3833333 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   19
3 2.416869e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 19 0.4000000 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   19
4 2.416511e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 16 1.5666667 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   16
5 2.416352e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 15 0.9500000 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   15
6 2.416334e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 15 2.3666667 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   15
```

Now we have split weekdays column appropriately, we can use `aggregate` function to calculate `mean` over desired grouping columns.

```
> aggregate(halflife ~ Weekday, data=mydf2, FUN = mean)
  Weekday  halflife
1  Friday 1.013889
```

If you want to group by `Weekday` as well as `Hour` then

```
> aggregate(halflife ~ Weekday + Hour, data=mydf2, FUN = mean)
  Weekday Hour   halflife
1  Friday   15 1.6583333 
2  Friday   16 1.5666667 
3  Friday   19 0.3916667 
4  Friday   22 0.4166667
```

As such first parameter of `aggregate` function here is a forumla object which supports  one ~ one, one ~ many, many ~ one, and many ~ many relationships. See `?aggregate` examples to understand how to use it.

I will give brief example of how to many to many relationships.

```
> set.seed(12345)
> mydf2 <- cbind(mydf2, newvar = rnorm(nrow(mydf2)))
> mydf2
            id                 weekdays       halflife Weekday     Day  Year Hour     newvar
1 2.417322e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 22 0.4166667 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   22  0.5855288
2 2.416892e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 19 0.3833333 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   19  0.7094660
3 2.416869e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 19 0.4000000 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   19 -0.1093033
4 2.416511e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 16 1.5666667 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   16 -0.4534972
5 2.416352e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 15 0.9500000 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   15  0.6058875
6 2.416334e+17 Friday, Aug 31, 2012, 15 2.3666667 mins  Friday  Aug 31  2012   15 -1.8179560
> aggregate(cbind(newvar,halflife) ~ Weekday + Hour, data=mydf2, FUN = mean)
  Weekday Hour     newvar  halflife
1  Friday   15 -0.6060343 1.6583333
2  Friday   16 -0.4534972 1.5666667
3  Friday   19  0.3000814 0.3916667
4  Friday   22  0.5855288 0.4166667
```